# Создание нового проекта в Android Studio Фламинго

Tags: android, android-studio

Пишу программы на С/С++, в Андроид/Фламинго новичок. При создании чистого проекта в структуре проекта отсутствует папка res/layout. Все методы поиска дают нулевой результат, но проект запускается, виртуальный телефон вижу, в реальный загружаю, все работает.

Проблема в том, что все уроки и книги начинают первые объяснения с этой папки и файла activity_main.xml, которого нет. Если создать проект с базовой активностью папка и файл есть, но есть другой код, объяснения  которому не нахожу. Использую Котлин.

Может кто-то пояснит отличие Фламинго (Котлин) в плане построения проекта с пустой активностью, от предыдущих версий и как быть с файлом activity_main.xml.

Comment: Теперь AS по умолчанию создает Compose проект, без xml разметки как раньше. Поэтому старые книги и уроки тут не применимы.

Comment: Спасибо, ситуацию понял.

Answer (score 2):

В Android Studio Flamingo произошел переход от классической разработки UI в виде XML к Jetpack Compose, где UI описывается в Kotlin коде.
https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose

Тем не менее, все еще возможна разработка и "старым" методом.
Для новых проектов в этом случае используйте шаблон Empty Views Activity.

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку.